# Is it possible to check string encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

In my application I import some text into database from files that users upload on site.
Database SQL Server 2005, text is stored `nvarchar` column, I use EF and L2SQL.

Users should make their files with UTF-8 but unfortunately some of them apparently used different encoding. In result some characters are invalid.

I'd like to find which records are valid. I use **utf8checker**. It works fine with original files, but when text is from database `IsUtf8` method always returns true.

Comment: "from database" - better check after upload and before all your code starts re-encoding it.

Comment: in the database, is it varbinary? nvarchar? image? varchar? text? ntext?

Comment: in database its nvarchar

Comment: nvarchar by itself doesn't mean anything... what DB (Oracle, SQL Server...) AND what are the DB setting for NVARCHAR AND what are your client settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SQL server will always store Unicode as UCS-2. So, you need to ensure that the data has the correct encoding at insert time rather than read time. Otherwise SQL server will garble it for you and I don't think there is a way to determine the original encoding after the data has been inserted - unless maybe you have the encoding definition in the record itself, like another column or the first few characters of your data element. Eg. - XML does it this way.

Hope this helps.